# trying to merge two list ,placing their item alternative to each other in pyhton

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

guys i have  to make one list ,by using two distinct list ,and items inside the final list is placed in such a order that ,first element of first list lie just after first element of second list,(lst1=[x1,x2,x3],   lst2=[y1,y2,y3] ,   lst=[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3])

**input**

```
lst1=[3,4,7]
lst2=[2,5,1]
ti=0
for yt in range(len(lst1)+1):
    if yt %2==0:
        lst1.insert(yt,lst2[ti])
        ti+=1
        
        
print(lst1)
```

**output**

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 7]
```

**expected**

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 7]
```

also wanna know my mistake .
any possible help will be appriciated

Comment: Your approach will fail as you alter `lst1.insert(...` while you iterate the same list `range(len(lst1, ...`

Comment: @stovfl Nah. If that were a problem, Pygirl's answer would fail as well.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: `yt` points to the index in the starting list. The list grows therefore `yt` becomes invalid.

Comment: @stovfl It doesn't become invalid. Not sure what you're not understanding. Did you check out Pygirl's version?

Comment: @HeapOverflow I'm not interested in Pygirl's version, i'm refering to this example and why it will fail.

Comment: @stovfl But that's not why it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218578/discussion-between-stovfl-and-heap-overflow).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) or [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
result = []
for x in zip(lst2, lst1):
    result.extend(x)
```

or

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(zip(lst2, lst1)))
```

---

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

the loop range is wrong in your code:

```
lst1=[3,4,7]
lst2=[2,5,1]
ti=0
for yt in range(len(lst1)+len(lst2)-1): # <------ here
    if yt %2==0:
        lst1.insert(yt,lst2[ti])
        ti+=1
        
        
print(lst1)
```

You can use `zip` and `itertool`'s `chain`

```
from itertools import chain
li = list(chain(*zip(lst2,lst1)))
```

**Or**

```
li = [j for i in zip(lst2,lst1) for j in i]
```

---

**li:**

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 7]
```

**Edit:**

**Explanation:**

```
3,4,7
0,1,2

first insertion at 0th pos: 
2,3,4,7
0,1,2,3

second insertion at 2nd pos:
2,3,5,4,7
0,1,2,3,4

third insertion at 4th pos:
2,3,5,4,1,7
0,1,2,3,4,5

range will be 0,1,2,3,4 [0,5)
```

Comment: i got what you are trying to tell me,but can you tell me why i am not getting desired result by using that code that i provided

Comment: see the explanation part you need range from 0 to 4(including), len will be 5

Comment: Why the `-1`? Works without that, too.

Comment: yeah it will work for len(6) also. To make the logic clear that's why make it -1. That will fail for `lst1=[3,4,7,9];
lst2=[2,5,1]` will only work for this case but not for all. That's why -1  because according  to the logic the length should be total length-1

Comment: It depends which whichever has the longest length (difference of 1 only). Use `-1` if `len(lst1) == len(lst2) -1` if vice versa use without -1

Answer (score 1):

```
expected = [x for tup in zip(lst2,lst1) for x in tup]
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lst1 = [3, 4, 7]
lst2 = [2, 5, 1]
lst3 = []
for i in zip(lst2, lst1):
    lst3.extend(i)
print(lst3)
```

Output will this:

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 7]
```